# What is the best way to use float numbers with decimal point in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, decimal

I did an investigation and I saw that there is a whole website to explain to you what is the correct way to use floats at: http://floating-point-gui.de/

In Java for example I was always using BigDecimal for the floats just to make sure that everything will work correctly without confusing me. For example:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("0.1");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("0.2");
BigDecimal c = a.add(b); // returns a BigDecimal representing exactly 0.3
                         // instead of this number: 0.30000000000000004 that can 
                         // easily confuse me
```

However in JavaScript I realized that there is not such thing as a build-in library (at least at the Math object that I've looked)

So the best way that I did find so far was to use a JavaScript library that it is doing exactly that! In my projects I am using this one: https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js

Although I think this is the best library I could find, the library doesn't really matter so much. My main questions are:

1. Is it the best way possible to use a library like `BigDecimal` the best way to use floats for JavaScript? or am I missing something? I want to do basic calculations like add, multiplying ...e.t.c.
2. Is there any other suggested way for example to add two floats in JavaScript?

For example, let's say that I want to have: `0.1 + 0.2` . With the `BigDecimal` library, I will have:

```
var a = new BigDecimal("0.1");
var b = new BigDecimal("0.2");

console.log(a.add(b).toString()); //returns exactly 0.3
```

So is there any other way to add 0.1 + 0.2 and have exactly 0.3, in JavaScript without having to actually round the number ?
For the reference the below example in JavaScript will not work:

```
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.2;
console.log(a + b); //This will have as an output: 0.30000000000000004
```

Comment: If you really don't want to use native binary floating point, then you're doing (some variation of) the right thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As all numbers in javascript are 64bit, in general the best way to do floating point aritmetic in javascript is to simply use numbers straight.

However, if you specifically have a problem where you need higher precision than what 64bits will provide, then you need to do something like that.

I urge you, however, to strongly consider if you have such a usecase or not.

If your problem is with some far-down decimals affecting your comparisons, there are functions to deal with that sort of thing specifically. I urge you to look up the Number.prototype.toFixed(n) function and also see [this dicussion on almostEquals](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/89) which proposes that you incorporate the use of an epsilon for float comparisons.

Comment: Hello @Mithon and thanks for the answer (you have a +1 for that :)). Ok, I completely understood your concerns, I just have one question. Is there any disadvantages if I use the library instead? I think the only thing mentioned is the storage and maybe the speed of the calculation? Correct me if I am wrong, but I prefer to always know that I will have a "correct" result for my simple maths knowledge, rather than the correct floating numbers calculation. I simply don't want to have in mind some more complex things in such a simple math calculation.

Comment: Performance is clearly an issue, as a js-library like that is implemented in javascript, while straight number aritmetic is implemented in native c++ (or whatever). With simple maths that perf will be negligible however. But I would ask myself: Do I want to learn to use javascript with its quirks or will I fight them every step of the way? Personally I'd rather learn to work with it.

Comment: Fair enough! I am probably the person who prefers the easy way then :)

Comment: Virtually all languages use the [IEEE fp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard so you likely to encounter the same problem each time you use a different language. Hence it may pay you to work out how to deal with this sort of number. While BigDecimal fixes a few problems you still have  to work out what to do which division, neither IEEE FP or BigDecimal can represent 1/7 precisely.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the toFixed(n) method if you are not relying on high precision:

```
var a = 0.1;
var b = 0.2;
var sum = a + b;
console.log(sum.toFixed(1));
```

Your calculation shows a precision lost on the 17th floating point which is no big issue in the most cases.
I would advice you to go with toFixed() if you want to get the output right.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to consider here.

A lot of times people use the term 'float' when they really mean to use fixed decimal

**Fixed Decimal**

US currency, for example, is a fixed decimal.

```
$12.40
$0.90
```

In this case, there will *always* be two decimal points.

If your values fit into the range of JavaScript integers `(2^53-1)` or `9007199254740991` then you can simply work in cents and store all your values that way.

```
1240
90
```

**Floating point decimal**

Now, floating point is where you deal with extreme ranges of numbers and the decimal point actually moves, or floats.

```
12.394
1294856.9458566
.0000000998984
49586747435893
```

In cases of floating point, accuracy to 53 significant *bits* (which means around 15 digits of accuracy).  For a lot of things, that is *good enough.*

**Big Decimal Classes**

You should only look at big decimal classes if you need something beyond the range of JavaScript native numbers.  BigDecimal classes are much slower than native math and  you have to use a functional style of programming rather than use the math operators.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support operator overloading, so there is no built-in way to do natural calculations like '0.1 + 0.2' with BigNumbers.

What you can do is use [math.js](http://mathjs.org), which has an expression parser *and* support for BigNumbers:

```
math.config({
  number: 'bignumber',  // Default type of number: 'number' or 'bignumber'
  precision: 64         // Number of significant digits for BigNumbers
});

math.eval('0.1 + 0.2'); // returns a BigNumber, 0.3
```

See docs: http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html

Answer (score 0):

You could convert operands to integers beforehand

(0.1 * 10 + 0.2 * 10) / 10

will give the exact answer, but people probably don't want to deal with that floating point round stuff